# How do I remove broken packages from Ubuntu while trying to install unity tweak tool

Tags: terminal

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool


Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going 
to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to run the command at the top it gives me this. I've tried autoclean among many other things. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: See this maybe : https://askubuntu.com/questions/874820/how-to-resolve-the-errors-that-show-up-when-trying-to-install-unity-tweak-tool/874824

Comment: I've already tried all of those possible solutions with no success